# Objects appear when finding a Plane

Tags: augmented-reality, point-clouds, google-project-tango

I'm trying to make a object appear when the device finds a plane, but i'm not too sure how to do thi, I've been messing with the TangoPointCloud script and the FindCloud function in there but am not having any success with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Findplane function in Tango API doesn't find planes automatically. You have to give screen coordinates as argument, then FindPlane finds plane equation at location you are pointing to. There are methods to find plane from densepoint cloud like SVD, RANSAC etc., you can use them.